# Differential equation with $\sin(xt)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $x'=x+t\sin(xt)$, how can I solve it?
I tried to substitute something, but that didn't led me to anything. I would appreciate any hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $u=xt$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{u}{t}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{u}{t^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{u}{t^2}=\dfrac{u}{t}+t\sin u$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{u}{t^2}+\dfrac{u}{t}+t\sin u$

$(t^3\sin u+tu+u)\dfrac{dt}{du}=t$